# ld ignores size of nobits input section

Tags: linker, ld, elf, linker-scripts

When working on a small 32-bit kernel for the x86 architecture I discovered something strange with how `ld` handles nobits sections.

In my kernel I define a `.bootstrap_stack` section which holds a temporary stack for the initialisation part of the system. I also hold symbols for the beginning and end of the stack. This input section is redirected to the `.bss` output section. Each output section of my kernel has a symbol for the beginning and end of the section.

The problem is that in the final executable the symbol for the end of the stack is *after* the end of the `.bss` section. In the below examples the symbols `stack_top` and `_kernel_ebss` (and `_kernel_end`) have the same value, which isn't what I wanted.

I expected `_kernel_ebss` to equal `stack_bottom`.

However once I rename `.bootstrap_stack` to `.bss` this does not happen. Removing `nobits` also works, but the resulting binary is considerably larger.

Here are the stripped files that reproduce my issue:

boot.s

```
section .bootstrap_stack, nobits ; this does not work
;section .bootstrap_stack        ; this works
;section .bss                    ; this also works

stack_top:
resb 8096
stack_bottom:

section .text
global _start
_start:
    hlt
    jmp _start
```

linker.ld

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xC0100000;

    _kernel_start = .;

    .text ALIGN(4K) : AT(ADDR(.text) - 0xC0000000)
    {
        _kernel_text = .;
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)
        _kernel_etext = .;
    }

    .bss ALIGN(4K) : AT(ADDR(.bss) - 0xC0000000)
    {
        _kernel_bss = .;
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
        *(.bootstrap_stack)
        _kernel_ebss = .;
    }
    _kernel_end = .;
}
```

Here are the symbols:

```
$ objdump -t kernel | sort
00000000 l    df *ABS*              00000000 boot.s
c0100000 g       .text              00000000 _kernel_start
c0100000 g       .text              00000000 _kernel_text
c0100000 g       .text              00000000 _start
c0100000 l    d  .text              00000000 .text
c0100003 g       .text              00000000 _kernel_etext
c0101000 g       .text              00000000 _kernel_bss
c0101000 g       .text              00000000 _kernel_ebss
c0101000 g       .text              00000000 _kernel_end
c0101000 l       .bootstrap_stack,  00000000 stack_top
c0101000 l    d  .bootstrap_stack,  00000000 .bootstrap_stack,
c0102fa0 l       .bootstrap_stack,  00000000 stack_bottom
```

By renaming `.bootstrap_stack` to `.bss` I get what I expected.

```
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 boot.s
c0100000 g       .text  00000000 _kernel_start
c0100000 g       .text  00000000 _kernel_text
c0100000 g       .text  00000000 _start
c0100000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
c0100003 g       .text  00000000 _kernel_etext
c0101000 g       .bss   00000000 _kernel_bss
c0101000 l       .bss   00000000 stack_top
c0101000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
c0102fa0 g       .bss   00000000 _kernel_ebss
c0102fa0 g       .bss   00000000 _kernel_end
c0102fa0 l       .bss   00000000 stack_bottom
```

My question is whether this is expected behaviour of ld. If yes, what is the problem with my example, because as far as I understand `.bss` is also a nobits section, but it produces the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.

Apparently you're not supposed to have a comma right after the name of the section. `objdump` includes the comma in the name of the section so that clearly shows that that is the mistake.

So

```
section .bootstrap_stack, nobits
```

should be

```
section .bootstrap_stack nobits
```